# SDL C++: if functions not working. Compiles fine - Logical error

Tags: c++, sdl, codeblocks

Hello People of Stackoverflowaria,

My if functions are not working. It's a logical error. Can someone spot the error? I've been looking through the code for ages... also, any way to improve my formatting / where I put my variables would be cool.

The logical error is all based around `bgtoggle`. The `if` statements are pointed out by the comments.

Thanks in advance!

Luca

Here's main.cpp:

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_opengl.h"
#include <iostream>

void drawBox( int xpos , int ypos , int bwidth , int bheight );
void drawCrossHair();

int width = 400;
int height = 800;

bool bgtoggle = false;

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
  SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 32 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16 );
  SDL_GL_SetAttribute( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );

  SDL_WM_SetCaption( "Our First Game" , NULL );
  SDL_SetVideoMode( width , height, 32 , SDL_OPENGL );
  glClearColor( 1 , 1 , 1, 1 );
  glViewport( 0,0 , width,height );
  glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );
  glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
  glLoadIdentity();
  glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

  bool isRunning = true;
  SDL_Event event;

  while ( isRunning )
  {
    while ( SDL_PollEvent( &event ) )
    {

      if ( event.type == SDL_QUIT )
            isRunning = false;

      if ( event.type == SDL_KEYUP && event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE )
            isRunning = false;

    //THIS IF STATEMANT
      if ( bgtoggle == false && event.type == SDL_KEYUP && event.key.keysym.sym ==  SDLK_b )
      {
            glClearColor( 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 );
            bgtoggle = true;
      }

      // AND THIS IF STATEMENT
      if ( bgtoggle == true && event.type == SDL_KEYUP && event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_b)           {
        {
            glClearColor( 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 );
            bgtoggle = false;
        }
      }

      glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
      glPushMatrix();
      glOrtho( 0 , width , height , 0 , -1 , 1 );

      glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glColor4ub( 255 , 80 , 80 , 255 );
        glVertex2f( 5 , 5 );
        glVertex2f( width - 5 , 5 );

        glColor4ub( 0 , 0 , 255 , 255 );
        glVertex2f( width - 5 , height - 5 );
        glVertex2f( 5 , height - 5 );
      glEnd();

      drawCrossHair();
      glPopMatrix();
      SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

    }

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}

void drawCrossHair()
{
 glBegin( GL_LINES );

        glColor4ub( 0 , 0 , 0 , 255); 
        glVertex2f( width / 2 - 5 , height / 2 );
        glVertex2f( width / 2 - 15 , height / 2 );

        glVertex2f( width / 2 + 5, height / 2 );
        glVertex2f( width / 2 + 15 , height / 2 );

        glVertex2f( width / 2 , height / 2 - 5 );
        glVertex2f( width / 2 , height / 2 - 15 );

        glVertex2f( width / 2 , height / 2 + 5 );
        glVertex2f( width / 2 , height / 2 + 15 );

    glEnd();

    glBegin( GL_QUADS );

        glVertex2f( width / 2 - 1 , height / 2 + 1 );
        glVertex2f( width / 2 + 1 , height / 2 + 1 );
        glVertex2f( width / 2 + 1 , height / 2 - 1 );
        glVertex2f( width / 2 - 1 , height / 2 - 1 );

    glEnd();

    glBegin( GL_POINTS );

        glVertex2f( width / 2 , height / 2 );

    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: Surely not all of this code is necessary to demonstrate your problem. For example, all of the drawing code.

Comment: @chris I just put it al there in case someone wanted it all.

Comment: But what are we going to do with it? If it's the if statements associated with polling for keyboard events that aren't working, what could we possibly hope to get from looking at completely unrelated drawing code? Just make it do some outputs and tell us what you expect to be output when you, e.g., press a certain key, and what's actually output.

Comment: Please show that you at least tried to understand what went wrong by stripping down all unnecessary details from your program so that the error still occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple. In your first `if` you set `bgtoggle` to true. This makes the condition for the second `if` true, which sets `bgtoggle` to false again.

You'd better do:

```
  if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP && event.key.keysym.sym ==  SDLK_b )
        bgtoggle = ! bgtoggle;

  if(bgtoggle)
        glClearColor( 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 );
  else
        glClearColor( 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 );
```

Comment: How should I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: got it. stackoverflow made me wait 5 minutes. Thanks! Unfortunately I cant vote up because I dont have enough reputation.

Comment: After nearly 2 years I now understand the difference between "if" and "else if". *sigh* Woe learning programming off the internet. I need to get a good book.